# Modify and rename JSON elements from MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to use some random fields from my db and  json encode them.

How can i change name - q; pic - p; var - v and remove the ranom id's from the array and add incremental id's?

```
[
    {
        "name": "some text",
        "a": "var1",
        "b": "var2",
        "c": "var3",
        "pic": "1.jpg",
        "var": "a",
        "id": 375
    },
    {
        "q": "another question",
        "a": "var 2.1",
        "b": "var 2.1",
        "c": "var 2.1",
        "var": "a",
        "id": 28
    }
]
```

to this

```
[
    {
        "q": "some text",
        "a": "var1",
        "b": "var2",
        "c": "var3",
        "p": "1.jpg",
        "v": "a",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "q": "another question",
        "a": "var 2.1",
        "b": "var 2.1",
        "c": "var 2.1",
        "v": "a",
        "id": 2
    }
]
```

Comment: Are you pulling this from the db with a query? If you are pulling the data with PHP and json_encoding it, I'm pretty sure you can use aliases in your query, then the alias will be used as the array key.

Comment: just use some alias in the selected fields, then reassign the id with some counter, then encode.

Comment: Yes i'm pulling it from the db

Comment: Then do it Before you encode it into JSON. It would be easier to manipulate. Show us some code please

Comment: This is really not a JSON question at all. As said by the last commenter, iterate your pulled records in PHP to create the output structure you want, then `json_encode` and output it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use an alias on those particular columns that you want. Add a simple counter while fetching those rows and assign them on the `id` index. Then finally, encode:

Since there are no fetching code, this will be just a rough example/idea:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database name', 'username', 'password'); // connect
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = '
    SELECT 
        name AS q,
        a, b, c,
        pic AS p,
        var AS v,
        id
    FROM table_name
'; // add alias

$query = $db->query($sql);
$i = 1; // simple counter
$data['data'] = array();
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { // fetch
    $row['id'] = $i; // assign counter
    $i++;
    $data['data'][] = $row; // push
}
// encode
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: `Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in` on this line `while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { // fetch`

Comment: add this below the connection `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` this is just some pseudo code, i don't think there's wrong with the query anyways http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7425/3

Comment: Thank you. It was an error with the query, my bad typing. The code works but it displays `{
    "data": [` instead of `data=[`

Comment: @m3tsys well if you'd have `data=[`, its not a valid json anymore :)

Comment: then how can i remove the `{
    "data": ` and the ending `}` ?